# How do I select top ranker by date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a user data base with rank.what I am looking is how do I select top rank person based on today's search?? and I need to do this in daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT id, rank, something 
FROM person 
WHERE date = DATE(NOW()) 
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(rank), id 
  FROM mytbl
 WHERE date = mydate
 GROUP BY id
```